# Multiplication on click show into input filed with Different ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am designing shopping cart functionality. And Fresher in jQuery My layout is

This is my design

[image]

I want to when click on increment and Decrements button then increment value and decrements value multiply into input field value below is my jQuery code

```
$('.increment-btn').on('click',function(){
    var $counter=$(this).closest('td').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0)
    {$counter.val(currentVal - 1);
    }
});
```

this is HTML code

```
<table Style="width:100%;" class="sumtable">
    <tr>
        <td id="info" Style="padding-left: 3%;width: 20%; ">Buy Price</td>
        <td > <span id="RS" style="color:#4286f4">₹</span> &nbsp;<input type="text" name ="f03" value="#BUY#" Style="border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #a0a6af;" id ="BUY" ></td>
        <td></td><td>&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;</td> 
        <!--td ><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" id="#c001#"></td-->
        <td>#CHECK#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="info" Style="padding-left: 3%; ">MRP Price</td>
        <td> <span id="RS" style="color:#4286f4">₹</span> &nbsp;<input name="num1" type="text" value ="#MRP#" Style="border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #a0a6af;" id ="MRP_#PRODUCTID#" class="CLASS_MRP"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="info" Style="padding-left: 3%;">Sell Price</td>
        <td> <span id="RS" style="color:#4286f4">₹</span> &nbsp;<input name="num2" type="text"   value="#SELL#" Style="border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #a0a6af;" ID="SELL_#PRODUCTID#" class="CLASS_SELL"  /></td>
    </tr>       
</table>
</div><br>
    <div Style="float:right;">
        <table Style="width:100%; float:right; line-height: 2;" >
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;">Your Profit</td>
            <td><span id="RS" style="color:#4286f4">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ₹ </span>&nbsp; <input name="num3" type="text" type="hidden" value="1" Style="border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #a0a6af; color:#2d992f; font-weight:700; text-align:center; " id="OUT_#PRODUCTID#"  class="CLASS_OUT"  >     <span id="liveResult"></span> </td> 
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:right;" id ="minimum">Minimum Quantity</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;"><input type="button" value="-" style="width: 30px;border-radius: 50%; background-color: white;height: 30px;    border: 1px solid #0953A3;" class="decrement-btn">
                <input id="AAA" type="text" Style="border:none; border-bottom:1px solid #a0a6af;text-align: center;" value="1" class="counter" >
                <input type="button" value="+" style="width: 30px;border-radius: 50%; background-color: white;height: 30px; border: 1px solid #0953A3;" class="increment-btn">
            </td>
            <td>


$(function () {
$('.increment-btn').on('click',function(){
    var $counter=$(this).closest('td').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    var total = 0;
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) 
    { 
        $counter.val(currentVal + 1);   

    }
});
$('.decrement-btn').on('click',function(){
    var $counter=$(this).closest('td').find('.counter');
    var currentVal = parseInt($counter.val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0)
    {$counter.val(currentVal - 1);
    }
});
```

});

this is fuction which i used its work only increment and decrement number but i want when click on increment button increment value multiply by input field value

Comment: You should post the entire code which the above function is used.

Comment: Please remove the angularjs tag as this is not angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be this help you

```js
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function() {
    var id=this.id;;
    var inc=id=="inc";
    var d = $("#input_data");
    var val = +d.val();
    if (inc)val++;else val--;
    d.val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"  id="dec"> - </button>  
<input type="number" id="input_data" value="1">        
<button type="button"  id="inc"> + </button>
```

Comment: it is allowing negative number and taking 3498374723497927347242, @man

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

Here i manage the user cant enter the **negative number in textbox,** and user cant fill the **more than 99999**.

```
$(function() {
  $(".but").on("click",function() {
    var id=this.id;;
    var inc=id=="inc";
    var d = $("#input_data");
    var val = +d.val();
    if (inc)val++;else val--;
    d.val(val);
  });
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button"  id="dec" class="but"> - </button>  
<input type="number" id="input_data" value="1" max-length="999999" min-length="0">        
<button type="button"  id="inc" class="but"> + </button>
```